# Excel VBA: Check that no items are selected on multiselect listbox without looping

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a few ListBoxes with MultiSelect enabled.

Is there a way to check that none of the items in the listbox is selected by the user without looping? For a long list, the macro takes too long to check with looping.

Comment: Have you tried re-initializing the listbox to a default, no selections?

Comment: no, but i'm not sure how that would help. I'm checking if any of the multiselect listboxes are not selected by the user. If the listboxes are selected, I will carry out other steps in my code.

Comment: Show your code. For a long list (or even a short one) it would be preferable to `Exit For` in the event that *any* value is selected. 99% of the time you will not need to iterate the entire list.

Answer (score 4):

There is no inbuilt property to check if anything is selected or not. Looping is the most natural way. If you have such a large dataset in listbox that is making it slow, the other way to check selected item count, on the fly, is to implement the change event and keep a count of selected items as and when they are checked.

---

```
Option Explicit

Dim lSelCount As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If lSelCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "At least one item selected"
    Else
        MsgBox "No selection"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim bVal As Boolean
    bVal = Me.ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex)

    If bVal Then
        lSelCount = lSelCount + 1
    Else
       lSelCount = lSelCount - 1
    End If
End Sub
```